# How to send Public Key while running ansible-playbook?

Tags: ssh, ansible, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am working on the vault-ssh secret engine method which is using the authorized CA for signing the keys and you can authenticate to the client with that signed certificate,

You can check this link:- https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/ssh/signed-ssh-certificates

I am able to log in to the client machine using the command:-

ssh -i id_rsa -i signed-vault.crt test@client-ip

same thing I need to do with ansible, but I find that in ansible there is no way to send the public key on the go, or while running the ansible-playbook command, you can send private key using the --private-key option.

So need help is there any way by which we can send the public key on the go or any work-around on this.

if needed more clarity on the vault-ssh-setup you can check out this blog

https://brian-candler.medium.com/using-hashicorp-vault-as-an-ssh-certificate-authority-14d713673c9a

Answer (score 0):

i am searching something on the google and find this github link :- https://gist.github.com/nehrman/3951a9f61083e462c60aeffcd942acb8

we can use the **set_fact** to get this thing done.

```
  - set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ r_tempfile.path }}/id_rsa"

    - set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-i {{ r_tempfile.path }}/signed"

    - set_fact:
        ansible_user: ansible
```

Thanks to the nehrman for writing this.
https://github.com/nehrman